# python list comprehension set max len

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to make list comprehension stop when n items are added to the new list?

e.g.,

```
[x for x in xrange(20) if len(<this>) < 10 ]
```

To confirm: I wants to limit the length of the resultant list to 10. "" is pseudocode for the current list being made. Im using python 2.7

Comment: <this> in the case above looks to be pseudocode for a reference to the list currently being constructed

Comment: I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Tichodroma He wants to only take the first 10 items, for example.

Comment: @Tichodroma: The asker wants to limit the length of the resultant list.

Comment: The first 10 should be a simple slice: `[:10]`. If there is some additional condition to *which* elements are added to the list, I can't see it from the question.

Comment: If you replace `xrange()` with an infinite generator then you'll never get a chance to slice it.

Comment: So perhaps @rikAtee should edit the question to give us a clue about the generator used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. But [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) can give you a generator that only yields a given number of items.

```
>>> list(itertools.islice('foobar', 3))
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

Comment: The neatest general way of doing this. It's worth noting that if you are using a sequence as the source, you could just do a normal list slice.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, but it will depend on the implementation of Python you are using, since it depends on the implementation of list comprehensions. The name of "this list comprehension" in CPython is "`_[1]`", so for example you could do the following (try it yourself, it really will work):

```
[i for i in xrange(20) if len(locals().get("_[1]")) < 10]
```

**It is very unlikely that you should be doing this with real production code.** It's absurdly obscure, and if someone is using any other implementation, it could break. Instead, just use a loop:

```
l = []
for i in xrange(20):
    l.append(i)
    if len(l) >= 10:
         break
```

`locals().get("_[1]")` works because Python needs to store the current list in some place during the list comprehension construction. "`_[1]`" was chosen somewhat arbitrarily since it is highly unlikely that anyone would use that as a variable name. If you happen to build a nested list comprehension, those will store lists in higher incremented variable names, eg, "`_[2]`" and "`_[3]`" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If `xrange` is the generator your use, just do

```
list(xrange(20))[:10]
```